# What is this format? -csv or Json or xml or any else?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, csv

I came across the following data:

```
Security Code\tSecurity Name\tGroup\tLTP\tChg\t% Chg\n533317\tOMKARCHEM\tB\t23.40\t3.90\t20.00\n526576\tTECHIN\tB\t14.30\t2.38\t19.97\n543636\tDCI\tB\t93.70\t15.60\t19.97\n523007\tANSALBU\tX\t102.95\t16.85\t19.57\n543614\tTIPSFILMS\tB\t524.95\t84.55\t19.20\n504648\tBOMBWIR\tX\t37.90\t5.65\t17.52\n543285\tRCAN\tM\t105.00\t15.50\t17.32\n526891\tMKTCREAT\tX\t11.00\t1.48\t15.55\n522231\tCONART\tX\t45.90\t6.05\t15.18\n533638\tFLEXITUFF\tB\t29.05\t3.55\t13.92\n540386\tONTIC\tX\t1.86\t0.21\t12.73\n524280\tKOPRAN\tB\t172.25\t18.25\t11.85\n531543\tJINDWORLD\tB\t277.70\t28.90\t11.62\n500144\tFINCABLES\tA\t493.85\t44.95\t10.01\n531201\tSHILCTECH\tX\t797.20\t72.45\t10.00\n536773\tJPOLYINVST\tB\t539.15\t49.00\t10.00\n542694\tPARSHVA\tB\t196.35\t17.85\t10.00\n543544\tJAYANT\tM\t607.20\t55.20\t10.00\n514360\tKRRAIL\tX\t54.55\t4.95\t9.98\n530271\tRICHUNV\tX\t8.27\t0.75\t9.97\n542842\tNIESSPK\tB\t104.20\t9.45\t9.97\n526473\tELEFLOR\tX\t10.42\t0.94\t9.92\n542627\tCHANDNIMACH\tX\t30.50\t2.75\t9.91\n543606\tCONTAINE\tM\t43.30\t3.90\t9.90\n532035\tUNISTRMU\tX\t21.15\t1.90\t9.87\n532005\tSAMINDUS\tX\t36.25\t3.25\t9.85\n542808\tNIESSPC\tB\t2.79\t0.25\t9.84\n532406\tAVANTEL\tX\t325.65\t29.15\t9.83\n542727\tCPML\tM\t33.00\t2.95\t9.82\n543176\t11MPR\tB\t8.64\t0.77\t9.78\n540811\tDML\tM\t13.50\t1.20\t9.76\n524606\tBERLDRG\tX\t9.87\t0.87\t9.67\n532395\tAXISCADES\tB\t214.25\t18.60\t9.51\n531281\tMARBLE\tX\t20.85\t1.80\t9.45\n542146\tSKIFL\tM\t21.00\t1.80\t9.38\n890169\tDYNPROPP\tB\t143.70\t12.10\t9.19\n507828\tANSALHSG\tX\t5.50\t0.46\t9.13\n543177\t11QPD\tB\t1.56\t0.13\t9.09\n523832\tMUKATPIP\tX\t8.29\t0.69\t9.08\n500220\tJASCH\tX\t180.35\t14.95\t9.04\n542651\tKPITTECH\tA\t711.90\t58.95\t9.03\n532215\tAXISBANK\tA\t900.25\t74.05\t8.96\n505250\tGGDANDE\tX\t74.95\t6.10\t8.86\n522074\tELGIEQUIP\tA\t490.90\t39.90\t8.85\n543327\tEXXARO\tB\t137.90\t11.20\t8.84\n541152\tGOYALALUM\tM\t136.10\t10.85\t8.66\n534755\tTRIOMERC\tX\t1.14\t0.09\t8.57\n539725\tGOKULAGRO\tB\t138.75\t10.95\t8.57\n505690\tBRADYM\tX\t169.65\t13.20\t8.44\n524628\tPARKERAC\tX\t10.34\t0.80\t8.39
```

What data format is this in?

Comment: It looks like [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) to me (tab (like comma) separated values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\t` is the tab character. `\n` is the new line character. Looks like TSV (tab-separated values), which is very similar in idea to CSV (comma-separated values).

Replacing those escaped characters with their real characters gives you the following data:

```
Security Code   Security Name   Group   LTP Chg % Chg
533317  OMKARCHEM   B   23.40   3.90    20.00
526576  TECHIN  B   14.30   2.38    19.97
543636  DCI B   93.70   15.60   19.97
523007  ANSALBU X   102.95  16.85   19.57
543614  TIPSFILMS   B   524.95  84.55   19.20
504648  BOMBWIR X   37.90   5.65    17.52
543285  RCAN    M   105.00  15.50   17.32
526891  MKTCREAT    X   11.00   1.48    15.55
522231  CONART  X   45.90   6.05    15.18
533638  FLEXITUFF   B   29.05   3.55    13.92
540386  ONTIC   X   1.86    0.21    12.73
524280  KOPRAN  B   172.25  18.25   11.85
531543  JINDWORLD   B   277.70  28.90   11.62
500144  FINCABLES   A   493.85  44.95   10.01
531201  SHILCTECH   X   797.20  72.45   10.00
536773  JPOLYINVST  B   539.15  49.00   10.00
542694  PARSHVA B   196.35  17.85   10.00
543544  JAYANT  M   607.20  55.20   10.00
514360  KRRAIL  X   54.55   4.95    9.98
530271  RICHUNV X   8.27    0.75    9.97
542842  NIESSPK B   104.20  9.45    9.97
526473  ELEFLOR X   10.42   0.94    9.92
542627  CHANDNIMACH X   30.50   2.75    9.91
543606  CONTAINE    M   43.30   3.90    9.90
532035  UNISTRMU    X   21.15   1.90    9.87
532005  SAMINDUS    X   36.25   3.25    9.85
542808  NIESSPC B   2.79    0.25    9.84
532406  AVANTEL X   325.65  29.15   9.83
542727  CPML    M   33.00   2.95    9.82
543176  11MPR   B   8.64    0.77    9.78
540811  DML M   13.50   1.20    9.76
524606  BERLDRG X   9.87    0.87    9.67
532395  AXISCADES   B   214.25  18.60   9.51
531281  MARBLE  X   20.85   1.80    9.45
542146  SKIFL   M   21.00   1.80    9.38
890169  DYNPROPP    B   143.70  12.10   9.19
507828  ANSALHSG    X   5.50    0.46    9.13
543177  11QPD   B   1.56    0.13    9.09
523832  MUKATPIP    X   8.29    0.69    9.08
500220  JASCH   X   180.35  14.95   9.04
542651  KPITTECH    A   711.90  58.95   9.03
532215  AXISBANK    A   900.25  74.05   8.96
505250  GGDANDE X   74.95   6.10    8.86
522074  ELGIEQUIP   A   490.90  39.90   8.85
543327  EXXARO  B   137.90  11.20   8.84
541152  GOYALALUM   M   136.10  10.85   8.66
534755  TRIOMERC    X   1.14    0.09    8.57
539725  GOKULAGRO   B   138.75  10.95   8.57
505690  BRADYM  X   169.65  13.20   8.44
524628  PARKERAC    X   10.34   0.80    8.39
```